# Method that returns greater value of two numbers

Tags: c#, methods

So I have this code

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("First Number = ");
        int first = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Second Number = ");
        int second = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Greatest of two: " + GetMax(first, second));
    }

    public static int GetMax(int first, int second)
    {
        if (first > second)
        {
            return first;
        }

        else if (first < second)
        {
            return second;
        }
        else
        {
            // ??????
        }
    }
```

is there a way to make GetMax return a string with error message or something when first == second.

Comment: Already part of the BCL: `Math.Max`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("First Number = ");
    int first = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("Second Number = ");
    int second = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Greatest of two: " + GetMax(first, second));
}

public static int GetMax(int first, int second)
{
    if (first > second)
    {
        return first;
    }

    else if (first < second)
    {
        return second;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Oh no! Don't do that! Don't do that!!!");
    }
}
```

but really I would simply do:

```
public static int GetMax(int first, int second)
{
    return first > second ? first : second;
}
```

Answer (score 45):

You can use the built in [`Math.Max` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.max%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: OP wants to return a string/error if the two values are equal.

Comment: In Unity this requires `using System;`

Answer (score 4):

Since you are returning greater number, as both are same, you can return any number

```
public static int GetMax(int first, int second)
{
    if (first > second)
    {
        return first;
    }

    else if (first < second)
    {
        return second;
    }
    else
    {
        return second;
    }
}
```

You can further simplify it to

```
public static int GetMax(int first, int second)
{
  return first >second ? first : second; // It will take care of all the 3 scenarios
}
```

Comment: Best and most logical solution.

Comment: OP wants to return a string/error if the two values are equal.  I think most people here are just reading the title, which is different to what the question actually is.

Answer (score 1):

If possible to use the List type, we can make use of the built in methods Max() and Min() to identify the largest and smallest numbers within a large set of values.

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
numbers.Add(10);
numbers.Add(30);
numbers.Add(30);
..

int maxItem = numbers.Max();
int minItem = numbers.Min();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("First Number: ");
        int number1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Second Number: ");
        int number2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        var max = (number1 > number2) ? number1 : number2;
        Console.WriteLine("Greatest Number: " + max);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to display the output like this

```
Console.WriteLine("Greatest of two: " + GetMaxString(first, second));
```

I'd have the GetMax function return a string:

```
public static string GetMaxString(int first, int second)
{
    return (first > second) ? first.ToString() : (second > first) ? second.ToString() : "The two values are equal";
}
```